# R wilcox.test by categorical subset error

Tags: r

I'm trying to specify catagorical subgroups, I found a [source](http://www.gardenersown.co.uk/education/lectures/r/nonparam.htm#stack_select) which suggests you can simply use this layout

```
wilcox.test(growth ~ sugar, data= carbs, subset= sugar %in% c("test", "C"))
```

However on my dataset it doesn't work, though the same format works if convert groups to numerical values in excel.

```
wilcox.test(Distance~Application, data= walking.dat,
            subset = Application %in% c("Control", "Cue-Lure"))

Error in wilcox.test.formula(Distance ~ Application, data = walking.dat,  : 
  grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels
```

Any suggestions would be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is amazing you can still see my deleted comments. I made two comments earlier, pointing out two possible issues.

**issue 1:**

It is highly likely that there is no `"Control"` or `"Cue-Lure"` in `walking.dat$Application`. I would suggest you try

```
with(walking.dat, unique(Application[Application %in% c("Control", "Cue-Lure")]))
```

to see what you get. Possibly you either get a single element, or nothing.

I can easily reconstruct the error you encountered. Consider the built-in R dataset `airquality`.

```
data(airquality)
unique(airquality$Month)  ## 5 6 7 8 9
wilcox.test(Ozone ~ Month, data = airquality, subset = Month %in% c(6, 7))  ## fine
wilcox.test(Ozone ~ Month, data = airquality, subset = Month %in% c(1, 7))  ## fail
```

In the second case, you get an error:

```
Error in wilcox.test.formula(Ozone ~ Month, data = foo, subset = Month %in%  : 
  grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels
```

because 1 is not an available value of `Month`.

**issue 2**

If both levels exist, then I guess your variable `Application` is `factor`. Check `class(Application)`. The problem of a factor, can be seen from here:

```
x <- factor(letters[1:4])
x[x %in% c("a", "b")]

#[1] a b
#Levels: a b c d
```

Note that the factor levels do drop after `%in%`. However, if you do:

```
x <- as.character(x)
x[x %in% c("a", "b")]

#[1] "a" "b"
```

Although you get characters, the formula method will coerce it into factors automatically. In this way, there is no danger that additional unused factor levels could break `wilcox.test()`.

Comment: Someone posted a comment a moment ago, they suggested that id need to run

`walking.dat$Application <- as.character(walking.dat$Application)`

before I run my test, and it fixes it. however im not sure why it fixes it

Comment: Worked perfectly :)

Comment: I see, just had a quick google of the `as.character()` function, we are just replacing that column in the data set with itself but specifying its character as apposed to a factor.